# Set slider values before binding

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind slider to start at certain value, like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/setbo6we/). But instead I'm getting this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxw1s5zb/20/).
My js-part look like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
             var value = valueAccessor();
       this.slider = $(element).attr("value", value());
    }
 };

 var testResult =  function (score){
                var self = this;
        self.score = ko.observable(score);
        self.id = ko.observable("slider-new");
        self.min = ko.observable(10);
        self.max = ko.observable(100); 
    };
    var result = new testResult(50);
   ko.applyBindings(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough to force an update:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
  init: function(element) {
    $(element).trigger("change");
  },
};
```